# Can I turn off the "duct tape mod" in Doom 3: BFG Edition?

Tags: doom-3-bfg-edition

> This BFG edition incorporates a version of the popular and necessary 'duct tape' mod, the PC gamer's answer to the original's insistence on a clear line between torch and gun - you couldn't use both at the same time. Here you can, and it's a wonder id ever released the game without this option.<sup>[1](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2012-10-19-doom-3-bfg-edition-review)</sup>

> The chief advancement ... is the addition of the so-called "duct tape" mod, that allows players to wield a weapon while the flashlight is on. The original Doom 3 kept the flashlight as a separate item, meaning you had to plunge the world into total darkness if monsters suddenly attacked while you were exploring a lightless area. The "duct tape" mod became so popular among PC users for improving the overall experience that it was -- thankfully -- included in this HD remake.<sup>[2](http://www.g4tv.com/games/xbox-360/66164/doom-3-bfg-edition/review/)</sup>

Is there an option to disable the now default "duct tape" mod, so as to imitate the original *Doom 3* settings? This is a common question under reviews, but I haven't seen it answered thus far.

Comment: Assuming you haven't already bought it, you should consider buying the original Doom 3 instead of BFG. I've heard nothing but negative things about it from fans. Apparently the graphics are worse than the original, and the additional mode is just rooms copied from the previous games.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can if you download this port:
https://www.moddb.com/mods/classic-rbdoom-3-bfg-edition

Comment: Why the downvote?